# declaration of 2 dimensional array having different type (one column float, anothe int)

Tags: visual-c++

Is there any way to declare 2 dim array that one column data type is int and the other is float in one line without using structure? for example one column is the score of student of class in float and another is the student code as integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without using a `struct` or `class` you cannot declare an array with two different types.